# How to change size of ImageButton without affecting icon size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I want to change `ImageButton` size (clickable area) but icon should stay same size. How to achieve that? I set `padding` but it did not affect button size at all.

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cross"
        android:tint="@color/colorBlack" />
```

Comment: set image in `android:src` attribute ?

Comment: I did. In background is ripple click effect shape.

Comment: set image in `app:srcCompat`?

Comment: This also didnt work

Comment: show the layout

Comment: i see a problem in your code

Answer (score 0):

When you only want to increase `ImageButton` size, then add             `android:scaleType="centerInside"` it will not reflect image icon size.Then for `ImageButton` you can provide size as much you want of `layout_width` and `layout_height`.